# PUT request: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]

Tags: python, json, python-requests, put

I am trying to send a PUT request using requests in python in the following way.

```
payload = {'value' : share}
r = requests.request("PUT", url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

As an answer I receive

```
A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
```

I looked thorugh all the questions here, but the solutions did not help me, unfortunately.

The problem seems to be on the network itself, where the following error occurs.

The payload is read in the network as `{"value": 12}`

Isn't this a correct JSONObject? I added the "[" manually, but it is still not accepted. Please help, I wasted hours to try to fix it.

Thank you!

Comment: Try: `r = requests.request("PUT", url, headers=headers, json=payload)`

Comment: Hi, I still get the error "A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]", unfortunately.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: My suspect is, that the communication network I am working with is faulty, or the error is somewhere else. This error is actually well discussed online.

Comment: What is the url? It is almost certainly a server side issue. It's definitely not a Python issue, at least.

Comment: I fixed it, but I am not sure, whether I understand why completely or not. It seems that the error was raised because of a faulty answer to my response, which was not in correct json format. I looked at the wrong place to fix the error. Hopefully this is going to help someone.